# Most favourable time to daven?

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer, mincha-afternoon-prayer

According to Sephardim, what is the most favourable time to daven: Shaharit, Mincha and Arvit?

Answer (score 1):

For Shacharit The Mitzva is to say Kriat Shema just before sunrise so that the Amida is recited at *Netz hachama* - when the sun rises, see Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 58,1:

> מצוה מן המובחר לקרות קריאת שמע כוותיקין (פירוש תלמידים. ורש"י פירש אנשים ענוים ומחבבים המצות) שהיו מכוונים לקרותה מעט קודם הנץ החמה (פירוש יציאת החמה כמו הנצו הרמונים) כדי שיסיים קריאת שמע וברכותיה עם הנץ החמה ויסמוך התפלה מיד בהנץ החמה ומי שיוכל לכוין לעשות כן שכרו מרובה מאד

For Mincha The *Sheilot utshuvot haRadvaz* (Rav David Ben Zimra Rav in Egypt 16th century interestingly Rav Ovadia Yosef was Cheif Rabbi in Egypt also 400 years later) 676 says that ideally Mincha should be done after *Mincha Ketana* (2.5 Halachik hours  before night time when dividing daylight into 12 hours) when possible because that was the time of the Korban Tamid. Ideally, only if one is certain he won't miss the time for Davening Mincha, he should Daven just before sunset making sure to complete it just before sunset:

> ולכתחלה מנחה קטנה עדיף שזו זמנה כנגד התדיר וזו כנגד ערבי פסחים שאינו תדיר וכן כתב הרב פ"ג מה' תפלה ואמ"ר חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן מצוה להתפלל עם דמדומי חמה שנאמר ייראוך עם 
>   שמש ואע"ג דלייטי עלה במערבא הנ"מ מאן דמאחר טפי אבל קודם ביאת השמש כמעט שפיר דמי

For Maariv/Aravit, the Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 235,1 says ideally it should be said from when one sees 3 small stars in the night

> זמן קריאת שמע אבלילה משעת יציאת בשלשה כוכבים קטנים

Comment: Is it to be understood from your comments about mincha,that Radvaz is imagining the mincha prayer takes 2.5 halachic hours or more?

Comment: @yaakovdeane no,  The Radvaz meant just if you won't have time to Daven before sunset but you will be able to Daven at Mincha Ketana Daven then earlier, but preferabaly try Daven just before sunset

Comment: Do Sefardim generally rule like that Radvaz? The Rambam doesn't agree, for instance

Comment: @doubleaa The Radvaz does indeed agree with the Rambam Hilchos Tefila 3,2 that the Ikar Zman is from 9.5 hours of daylight at mincha Ketana as opposed to the opinion of the Tur and the Rosh who say the Ikar zman is even from 6.5 hours of daylight Mincha Gedola. For regular working men they would fix a time  inorder not to miss Zman Mincha. The Radvaz is saying that for someone who is a Zariz like yourself who could make sure to Daven just before sunset should do so as you would never let the time pass and miss mincha.Eliyahu was answered at Har Hacarmel at sunset so it would be an eis ratzon

Comment: No, the Rambam thinks the ideal time only lasts until Plag. After Plag close to sunset is Bedieved.

Comment: @DoubleAA the Kesef Mishna explains that the only reason why the Rambam says the time of Plag Hamincha is to make sure that one who Davens Maariv like Rabbi Yehuda should have davened Mincha before plag. But the Rambam himself says that one davens Mincha till Shekia if he wants to do like Rabanan and and Daven maariv after Shekia רבינו שהו"ל לכתוב וזמן המנחה קטנה מתשע שעות ומחצה עד שתשקע החמה אבל נראה שכיון למה שכתב הרא"ש בשם הגאון דמאן דמקדים ומצלי ערבית תו לא מצי לצלויי מנחה אלא עד פלג המנחה כר"י דאם איתא לדרבי יהודה ליתא לדרבנן ואם איתא לדרבנן ליתא לדר' יהודה וכן אי צלי תפלת המנחה עד הערב

Comment: Interesting theory.

Comment: @rhhaokip i noticed that you're a big admirer of Rabbi Ovadia Yosef Ztzl, which is the reason why i referenced that he inherited the position of chief Rabbi in Egypt in the 1940s an extremely prestigious position that was Rav Davin Ben Zimra's position 400 years earlier a Rabbi who Rav Ovadia revered and seeked to emulate. In 1973, as Chief Sephardic Rabbi of Israel, he ruled, based on Rav David Ben Zimra and other opinions, that the Ethiopian Beta Israel were Jews